# One CNAME for two Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

can I use one CNAME record for two Azure Web App without a third-party service or services Azure? For example, so that I call testcname1.com/api in the code and the traffic goes for example to the web app test-api, and if I use testcname1.com/indentity the traffic goes to the web app test-indentity. Two Web Apps test-indentity and test-api one CNAME testcname1.com. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On a pure DNS level, you can't point a CNAME entry to two different other adresses.

[Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) is designed to do exactly what you want, but if I understand you correctly, you don't want to use other services.

As an alternative, you could set up a *third* AppService and host a reverse proxy, e.g. [ngnix](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/) using [WebApp for Containers](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/containers/). Or use IIS features directly, e.g. [like this](https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/).

As Lex Li pointed out, you could also use one of your existing app services as a [reverse proxy](https://tomssl.com/2015/06/15/create-your-own-free-reverse-proxy-with-azure-web-apps/) in addition to what it is already doing. Depends on how strongly you want to couple your services. Personally, I would probably use a dedicated instance just as a proxy, but both approaches can be valid.

Comment: A "third" AppService is not really necessary, as existing ones can add reverse proxy functionality easily.

Comment: Good point, at least for Windows AppServices it should be possible. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Traffic Manager does exactly what you want I think.
It is not free but for light/moderate load should be (very) cheap.
Does health checks as well.

from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/traffic-manager/
 - $0.54 per million queries
 - $0.36 per Azure endpoint/month